# Is this subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ a real subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We were asked to answer the following question:

Which of the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$ are real subspaces?

$$V_1:=\{(0,x,2x,3x)|x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$V_2:=\{(x^4,x^3,x^2,x)|x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$V_3:=\{(x,y,0,0)|x,y\in \mathbb{R},x>y\}$$

I’m a bit confused, since I’m used to writing subspaces with vectors and not real numbers. How should this exercise be solved?

Comment: Do you mean a real vector space? In this case every space except $V_2$

Comment: vectors in $R^4$ can be represented as 4-tuples of real numbers. They probably ask you which of these is a vector subspace. Do you know what it is?

Comment: x*(0,1,2,3) is a  vector and it is easy to see if it is a subspace , also the two others are vectors , write them as columns if you are only used to column vectors

Comment: How would you write vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$ normally? If you prefer column vectors, then just pretend that they are\begin{align}V_1&:=\left\{\pmatrix{0\\x\\2x\\3x}:x\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\V_2&:=\left\{\pmatrix{x^4\\x^3\\x^2\\x}:x\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
V_3&:=\left\{\pmatrix{x\\y\\0\\0}:x,y\in \mathbb{R},x>y\right\}\end{align}instead.

Comment: @ 
julio_es_sui_glace what about V3, are you sure?

Comment: How come $V_2$ isn’t a subspace? Can’t you multiply/ add whatever you want and it still stays in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Mimir2902 Take, for example, $(16, 8, 4, 2) \in V_2$ (note: it is in $V_2$, as it is exactly what you get when you put $x = 2$). What about if you multiply it by $3$? You get $(48, 24, 12, 6)$. Does that lie in $V_2$? If so, what $x$ makes $(x^4, x^3, x^2, x) = (48, 24, 12, 6)$?

Comment: Ok great, thanks for all your help!

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious enough about $V_3$... a similar trick works but where it is instead "*What about if you multiply it by $-1$?*" or "*What about if you multiply it by $0$?*"  Sure $V_3$ is closed under addition, but that is only one of many properties to check.